# How to access callback on grunt task set up in initConfig

Tags: javascript, callback, gruntjs

I've got an issue that I can't seem to resolve. I have tried a couple different ways, but nothing is working yet.

I am using grunt-messageformat to create my i18n localized copy. I have 2 folders with languages in them and I'd like to have grunt automatically generate the correct output for each folder (language).

The task that got me closest is this:

```
grunt.registerTask("ReadFolders", "Read the language folders in app/data/i18n/", function () {
  // Returns an array of the paths to the language folders.
  // ['app/data/i18n/en', 'app/data/i18n/key', ...]
  var languageFolders = grunt.file.expand("app/data/i18n/*");
  var path;
  var languageName;
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < languageFolders.length; i++) {
    path = languageFolders[i];
    languageName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length);

    grunt.config.set("mFormat.locale", languageName);
    grunt.config.set("mFormat.inputdir", "app/data/i18n/" + languageName);
    grunt.config.set("mFormat.output", "app-dist/test/js/locales/" + languageName + "/i18n.js");

    grunt.task.run("messageformat:all");
  }
});
```

This also uses the following code for my messageformat task, which is set up in initConfig:

```
messageformat: {
  all: {
    locale: "<%= mFormat.locale %>",
    inputdir: "<%= mFormat.inputdir%>",
    output: "<%= mFormat.output%>"
  }
}
```

The problem is that my loop in 'readFolders' runs through twice before the messageFormat task runs, which means the task runs twice, but both times it uses the last values for the mFormat variables.

I don't see any examples of how to access a callback of a task that is set up using initConfig.

Any thoughts? Or other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Another option I had considered was passing in the 3 variables to the task, but I wasn't sure how to do that either...  Something like grunt.task.run("messageformat:all", {locale: "something", inputdir: "somethingElse", output:"anotherThing"});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I didn't find a way to do what I had originally asked... But I found a good workaround that fulfills my needs. Instead of running the task for each folder, I instead rewrite the messageformat config dynamically for each language.

```
grunt.registerTask("ReadFolders", "Read the language folders in app/data/i18n/", function () {
  // Returns an array of the paths to the language folders.
  // ['app/data/i18n/en', 'app/data/i18n/key', ...]
  var languageFolders = grunt.file.expand("app/data/i18n/*");
  var path;
  var languageName;
  var locale;
  var messageFormat = {};
  var i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < languageFolders.length; i++) {
    path = languageFolders[i];
    languageName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, path.length);

    locale = languageName;
    if (languageName === "key") {locale = "en"; }

    messageFormat[languageName] = {
      locale: locale,
      inputdir: "app/data/i18n/" + languageName,
      output: "app-dist/test/js/locales/" + languageName + "/i18n.js"
    };

  }

  grunt.config.set("messageformat", messageFormat);

  grunt.task.run("messageformat");
});
```

After quite an exhaustive search, I think this is the only possible (and quite frankly, in my case, the better) solution.

Still happy to hear about any other ideas if anyone's got any.